# how to get only boolean value from a nested array

Tags: javascript

This might seems silly, but I'm trying it from long time.

```js
var parentArray = [
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.17249417249417248],
  [0.8181398601398602, null],
  [0.8181398601398602, 0.47785547785547783],
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.47785547785547783]
];

function containsNull(arr) {
  return (function() {
    return arr.filter(e => {
      if(e.some(el => el == null)) return true
    })
  })();
}

console.log("-->", containsNull(parentArray))
```

here I'm getting output as

```
> "-->" Array [Array [0.8181398601398602, null]]
```

but I don't need the array as return value. `I just want true or false that's all`.

```
i.e, 

"-->" true
```

How to achieve this? even using load-ash library is good to go!

Comment: why don't you: `return array.includes(null) === true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var parentArray = [
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.17249417249417248],
  [0.8181398601398602, null],
  [0.8181398601398602, 0.47785547785547783],
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.47785547785547783],
];

const result = parentArray.some((a) => a.includes(null));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is good logically, `Some` will return boolean by iterating, therefore one must use a method which return boolean inside it. i.e `includes` which returns boolean.

Comment: yup, @VikasAcharya that is correct

Comment: But there is one problem, When there no null value it crashes. it is not returning false.

Comment: It does return false...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using a multidimensional array, so you could just flatten it with `Array.prototype.flat` and use `Array.prototype.includes` to check if the flattened array contains `null`.

```js
let parentArray = [
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.17249417249417248],
  [0.8181398601398602, null],
  [0.8181398601398602, 0.47785547785547783],
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.47785547785547783]
];

const containsNull = (arr) => arr.flat().includes(null)

console.log(containsNull(parentArray))
```

The following would flatten arrays of n-dimensions and check if it contains `null`:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}

let parentArray = [
  [[[[0.49988811188811194, 0.17249417249417248]]],
  [0.8181398601398602, null],
  [0.8181398601398602, 0.47785547785547783]],
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.47785547785547783]
];

const containsNull = (arr) => flatten(arr).includes(null)

console.log(containsNull(parentArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.some()` method on both parent and child array.

```js
var parentArray = [
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.17249417249417248],
  [0.8181398601398602, null],
  [0.8181398601398602, 0.47785547785547783],
  [0.49988811188811194, 0.47785547785547783]
];

function containsNull(arr) {
  return arr.some(list => list.some(ele => !ele))
}

console.log(containsNull(parentArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you just want to know if there is any null in any subarray
I would personally flatten the array and use some() after that
Here is my answer:

```js
const containsNull = (arr) => arr.flat(Infinity).some(el => !el);
```

Comment: yo i posted this first

Comment: and btw your code would also return true if the array contained `false` (OP asked for `null` only)

Comment: It's already posted, I guess U have to refresh that page to see the posted answers. Thank you